# Best approach to include JSON content in an object that will be serialised by a Jackson Mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am using Jackson Mapper object to marshal objects into JSON. It works great but sometimes I need to include some specific JSON that is not really a property of the object to be marshalled. If I create a String property like "extraJSON" and put JSON content there, when that object is marshalled extraJSON will be escaped, so ends up being some kind of JSON inside JSON.
I have tried creating a property of type JsonObject (Java 8 JSON) but is not marshalled correctly.

Any ideas on how to solve this? So far I am using Local classes (which I create on the fly and use a "Object" type property), which works, but is an ugly workaround.

Comment: Have you tried @JsonRawValue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty basic example of using @JsonRawValue for marshalling a class member as JSON rather than as a attribute containing an escaped JSON string.  Don't know if applies to your scenario but hope it helps.

```
package com.spring.jackson.rawjson;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonRawValue;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.junit.Test;

public class RawJsonTest {

    public static class PojoWithRawJsonMember {

        private final String member1;
        private final String member2;
        private final String rawJsonMember1;

        public PojoWithRawJsonMember(String member1, String member2, String rawJsonMember1) {
            this.member1 = member1;
            this.member2 = member2;
            this.rawJsonMember1 = rawJsonMember1;
        }

        @JsonProperty("member1")
        public String getMember1() {
            return member1;
        }

        @JsonProperty("member2")
        public String getMember2() {
            return member2;
        }

        @JsonRawValue
        public String getRawJsonMember1() {
            return rawJsonMember1;
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void jsonRaw_shouldMarshalRawJson() throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        PojoWithRawJsonMember thingToMarshal = new PojoWithRawJsonMember("value1", "value2", "{\"key\":\"value\"}");
        String marshalled = mapper.writeValueAsString(thingToMarshal);
        assertEquals("{\"rawJsonMember1\":{\"key\":\"value\"},\"member1\":\"value1\",\"member2\":\"value2\"}",
                marshalled);
    }
}
```

@JsonRawValue works when serializing.  It will not apply to deserialization as far as my understanding from the JavaDocs.